# How to use enum in a parameterized constructor?

Tags: java, eclipse, enumeration

I have an assignment that asks me to create enumeration types. My question is, after I initialize them, how do I bring them into the default and parameterized constructors? i tried the following but it doesn't work... any ideas? Thanks

```
package magazine;
import paperPublication.PaperPublication;


public class Magazine extends PaperPublication {

    private enum paperQuality {LOW, NORMAL, HIGH};
    private enum issuingFrequency {WEEKLY, MONTHLY, YEARLY};

    public Magazine() {
        paperQuality = null;   //doesn't work
        issuingFrequency = null;    //doesn't work
    }

    public Magazine (double price, int numberOfPages, enum paperQuality  //doesn't work, enum issuingFrequency  //doesn't work) {

    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing better than the official tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Not directly related but if the enum is private, no one will be able to construct an instance of this class other than itself. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 6):

This is a type definition:

```
private enum paperQuality ...
```

But you don't actually have a field of that type declared. Try something like this:

```
private enum PaperQuality {...};
private PaperQuality paperQuality;
```

The first line defines the PaperQuality enum, defining the various values that any PaperQuality can hold. The second line creates a private field that is of that type, named `paperQuality`. The constructor could look like this:

```
public Magazine (double price, int numberOfPages, PaperQuality paperQuality) {
    ...
    this.paperQuality = paperQuality;
}
```

Comment: @jsan: I'm glad to have helped. If this answered your question sufficiently, please mark it as the "answer" so people know that you got the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You've declared the type but not the instance. You'll want...

```
        public enum PaperQuality {LOW, NORMAL, HIGH};
        public enum IssuingFrequency {WEEKLY, MONTHLY, YEARLY};

        PaperQuality paperQuality;
        IssuingFrequency issuingFrequency;

        public Magazine() {
            paperQuality = null; 
            issuingFrequency = null; 
        }

        public Magazine (double price, int numberOfPages, PaperQuality paperQuality){
          //logic here
        }
```

I suggest you read a tutorial on Java enums.

Answer (score 1):

`enum` keyword is like `class` keyword: it defines a type, not a variable.

You code is similar to the following:

```
public class Magazine extends PaperPublication {

   private class paperQuality { /* something */ }; // note class instead of enum
   private class issuingFrequency { /* something */ };

   public Magazine() {
       paperQuality = null;   //doesn't work -- beacuse paperQuality is a class
       paperQuality a; // does work because class name is suitable for variable definition
       a = null; // you can assign null to class variables
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable of the enumerated type:

`private paperQuality quality;`

(`enum paperQuality { ... }` just defines the enum type, it does not create a variable!).

Also, you cannot assign `null` to an enumerated type, it must be one of the enumerated values (i.e. `LOW`).

Answer (score 0):

For instance, you can create enum in the body of class

```
enum Sex {
    MALE,
    FEMALE
}
```

Also, you can create a separate class. Then declare the variable with enum type,and in the parentheses of the constructor, specify the type that you created

```
private Sex enSex;
private String personName;
private int personAge;
private double personWeight;

public Person(String name, int age, double weight, Sex enSex) {
    this.personName = name;
    this.personAge = age;
    this.personWeight = weight;
    this.enSex = enSex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private enum paperQuality {LOW, NORMAL, HIGH};
private enum issuingFrequency {WEEKLY, MONTHLY, YEARLY};
```

First create a variable for the enum type.

```
paperQuality paperqual;
issuingFrequency issuingfre;
```

then you can use those enum variable to assign values

```
public Magazine() {
    paperqual= null;  
    issuingfre= null;   
}

public Magazine (paperQuality pq,issuingFrequency isq) {
   paperqual = pq;
   issuingfre = isq;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

enum isn't a datatype its more like the "class" keyword. The datatypes in your example are paperQuality and issuingFrequency. So:

```
public Magazine (double price,
     int numberOfPages,
     paperQuality quality,
     issuingFrequency freq) {

}
```

Comment: My answer is the same as all the others on here. Someone want to explain the down votes?